# What is the proper name of this class of rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

There is a property of rings that seems to be quite natural, but I can't seem to find a short name for it. A commutative ring with unit $R$ has this property if and only if it has no divisors of $0$, and its field of fractions is a characteristic $0$ field. An equivalent condition is, I believe, that if a polynomial in $R[x]$  is uniquely determined by the corresponding map. In any case, it's quite a mouthful.

**Question:** What is this property called?

Comment: From your second sentence, the property is just being an integral domain of characteristic 0 (all rings have a characteristic, not just fields).

Comment: I guess I would just call it "an integral domain of characteristic 0"... But your statement about polynomials is not true: $R$ could also be an infinite integral domain of characteristic $p$.

Comment: I didn't realise rings have characteristics; thank you a lot!

Comment: If $R$ is a ring, the characteristic of $R$ is the additive order of $1 \in R$ (or $0$ if it has infinite order). This definition makes sense for arbitrary rings, not necessarily commutative, but the characteristic is no longer necessarily prime, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ has characteristic $n$.

Comment: Just to clarify (even though @QiaochuYuan's example also does this): The non-commutativeness is not what allows for non-prime characteristics. Rather, it is the existence of zero-divisors.

Answer (score 3):

*Getting this out of unanswered-limbo*

---

An integral domain's field of fractions has characteristic $0$ exactly when the integral domain's characteristic is $0$.

I'm not aware of any special term for them.